# Appropriate way to override Model __getattr__ in 1.4

Tags: python, django, django-models

What's the appropriate way of overriding the a Model class's
**getattr** in Django 1.4?

I have a model structure like:

```
class Main(models.Model):
    [blah]

class Detail(models.Model):
   main = models.ForeignKey(Main)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   value= models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I had overridden my Main.*getattr*_ so I could reference Detail
records as though they were normal Main attributes. e.g. a simple meta-
model pattern like

```
>>> m = Main.objects.create()
>>> Detail.objects.create(main=m, name='name', value='value')
>>> print m.name
'value'
```

To do this, my pre-1.4 **getattr** looked like:

```
def __getattr__(self, attrname):
    qs = self.details.filter(name=attrname)
    c = len(qs)
    if c == 0:
        raise AttributeError
    elif c == 1:
        return qs[0].value
    else:
        return [d.value for d in qs]
```

This worked perfectly until I upgraded to 1.4. Now I get all types
"attribute X does not exist" errors. I tried something like the
following, but had no luck. It seems to especially conflict with the
"_*_cache" attributes Django generates for ForeignKey references.

```
def __getattr__(self, attrname):
    try:
        return super(Main, self).__getattr__(attrname)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    qs = self.details.filter(name=attrname)
    c = len(qs)
    if c == 0:
        raise AttributeError
    elif c == 1:
        return qs[0].value
    else:
        return [d.value for d in qs]
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: This is a good time to stop and ask: why the H-E-double-hockey-sticks are you doing *that*? Not only does it look like a dirty hack, it's also *hugely* inefficient, generating a database query every time you access an attribute on the instance. You're not even caching anything.

Comment: Admittedly, my case is unusual. To describe it briefly, my model allows users to define their own custom models. Caching is trivial to add, which I've left out for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Digging through the new model code, it seems the backend has been changed substantially, so that the Model class no longer has a `__getattr__` to override. Instead, I need to call `object.__getattribute__`, which the base model inherits from. However, Django stores cached data in special attributes, which need to be properly handled.

My new `__getattr__` now looks like:

```
def __getattr__(self, attrname):
    try:
        return super(Main, self).__getattribute__(attrname)
    except AttributeError:
        if attrname.startswith('_prefetched'):
            raise
    qs = self.details.filter(name=attrname)
    c = len(qs)
    if c == 0:
        raise AttributeError
    elif c == 1:
        return qs[0].value
    else:
        return [d.value for d in qs]
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but [`__getattribute__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) might work:

```
class Main(models.Model):
    def __getattribute__(self, attrname):
        try:
            return super(Main, self).__getattribute__(attrname)
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                return self.__getattr__(attrname)
            except AttributeError:
                # do your database accessing
```

But as Chris Pratt said, this is not a bit efficient. You might want to consider caching your attributes.

Comment: `getattr(self, name)` will call `self.__getattribute__(name)`, leading to infinite recursion.

Comment: This one causes `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`